# CheckBox not being checked using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a arrayList which is `var totalCheckBoxArray=[1,2,3];`

I have checkboxes which has value 1 and 2 and 3 :

```
  <div class="card-body">
   <h5>Document List</h5>
   <div class="form-check">
      <div class="form-group" id="documents">
         <label> <input id="check_id1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk1" > <span>Invoice</span>
         <br>
         </label>
         <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
         <label> <input id="check_id2" type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk2" > <span>Packing List</span>
         <br>
         </label>
         <label> <input id="check_id3" type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk3" checked=""> <span>OTHERS</span>
         <br>
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In another variable i have list coming and stored in

```
trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious=[  
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":1,
      "docName":"Invoice",
      "docNameEng":"Invoice",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":null
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":2,
      "docName":"Packing List",
      "docNameEng":"Packing List",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":null
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":3,
      "docName":"OTHERS",
      "docNameEng":"OTHERS",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":"add"
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":3,
      "docName":"OTHERS",
      "docNameEng":"OTHERS",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":2,
      "othersDescription":"adffff"
   }
]
```

i need to compare the values of `totalCheckBoxArray` to value of `trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious.docId` and need to make checked the checkbox ,if their value matches. For example: if totalCheckBoxArray with value 1 matches with any trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious.docId =1,then `Invoice` must be checked. So I tried like this but it is not being checked.

```
 if(trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious){ 
  for (var i = 0; i <trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious.length ; i++) {
   for(j=0;j<totalCheckBoxArray.length;j++){

        if (totalCheckBoxArray[j] == trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious[i].docId) {
            console.log("entered in check");
            $(".chk"+(i+1)).prop('checked',true);
        } 
        else {
            $(".chk"+(i+1)).prop('checked', false);
             }

    }       
    }

     }
```

Comment: Do you get the debug-output `entered in check` inside the console?

Comment: yes  console.log("entered in check"); is printed four times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```js
var trDataSecondTable = {docLetterPrevious:[]};
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious=[  
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":1,
      "docName":"Invoice",
      "docNameEng":"Invoice",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":null
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":2,
      "docName":"Packing List",
      "docNameEng":"Packing List",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":null
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":2,
      "docName":"OTHERS",
      "docNameEng":"OTHERS",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":"add"
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":3,
      "docName":"OTHERS",
      "docNameEng":"OTHERS",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":2,
      "othersDescription":"adffff"
   }
]

var totalCheckBoxArray=[1,2,3];

if(trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious){ 
  for (var i = 0; i <trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious.length ; i++) {
   for(j=0;j<totalCheckBoxArray.length;j++){

        if (totalCheckBoxArray[j] == trDataSecondTable.docLetterPrevious[i].docId) {
            console.log("entered in check");
            $(".chk"+(i+1)).attr('checked',true);
        } 
        

    }       
    }

     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
   <h5>Document List</h5>
   <div class="form-check">
      <div class="form-group" id="documents">
         <label> <input id="check_id1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk1" > <span>Invoice</span>
         <br>
         </label>
         <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
         <label> <input id="check_id2" type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk2" > <span>Packing List</span>
         <br>
         </label>
         <label> <input id="check_id3" type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk3" checked=""> <span>OTHERS</span>
         <br>
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thnk u helped me alot :) hehe

Answer (score 2):

with document.querySelectorAll take all the input and insert their respective values in an array. Iterate over the data and compare if the id is present in that array. If it is present, mark the input with corresponding value as true

```js
var data=[  
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":1,
      "docName":"Invoice",
      "docNameEng":"Invoice",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":null
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":2,
      "docName":"Packing List",
      "docNameEng":"Packing List",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":null
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":3,
      "docName":"OTHERS",
      "docNameEng":"OTHERS",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":1,
      "othersDescription":"add"
   },
   {  
      "letterNo":13,
      "docId":3,
      "docName":"OTHERS",
      "docNameEng":"OTHERS",
      "docFile":null,
      "entryBy":"user98",
      "entryDate":"2019-02-05 13:03:02",
      "seqNo":2,
      "othersDescription":"adffff"
   }
]
var val=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var arr=[];
val.forEach((e)=>arr.push(Number(e.value)))
data.forEach((e)=>{
if(arr.includes(e.docId))
{
val.forEach((x)=>e.docId==x.value?x.checked=true:false)
}
})
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
   <h5>Document List</h5>
   <div class="form-check">
      <div class="form-group" id="documents">
         <label> <input id="check_id1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk1" > <span>Invoice</span>
         <br>
         </label>
         <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
         <label> <input id="check_id2" type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk2" > <span>Packing List</span>
         <br>
         </label>
         <label> <input id="check_id3" type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk3" > <span>OTHERS</span>
         <br>
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```